# Posting to wordpress site hosted on VPS with REST API returning successful code but not working

Tags: python, json, wordpress, nginx

I had a wordpress website on a shared hosting plan, just recently got a VPS and downloaded CLouldPanel to launch the site once again on Wordpress. I got it to work except for the part where my python code I have to automatically publish posts with the REST API. This no longer works.

I have this code here:

```
import requests
import json

# Set the endpoint URL of your WordPress website
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'

# Set the credentials for authentication
username = 'myusr'
password = 'mypass'

# Set the post content
title = 'Test post'
content = 'This is the content of my new post.'

# Set the request headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Set the request data
data = {
    'title': title,
    'content': content,
    'status': 'draft'
}

# Send the request
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, auth=(username, password))

print (response.headers)
print (response.text)

# Check the response
if response.status_code == 201:
    print('Post created successfully!')
else:
    print('Error creating the post. Status Code:', response.status_code)
    print('Error message:', response.text)
```

The password is an authentication password, not my login password so that should be good.

The line that prints out the header shows this in part of the response: **'Allow': 'GET',**
I am assuming this means that you can only run get requests and not post, which is the core of the issue here.

I have added lines of code to the nginx config file and made it so that the headers have POST as well, but that didnt even work. The site health tools says my REST API is working too.

I have tried the code on a site that is currently on a shared hosting plan and it worked without any issue. So i knnow this has something to do with my server